# NSURLConnection finished with error 1200, now 1202?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url

All my api calls were working perfectly but after upgrading `Xcode` to the latest version `Xcode 9.4.1`, none of my api calls work.

I first received `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200` but after adding:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

to `info.plist`, I now receive `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1202`. I have confirmed that there is not a problem with the domain I am connecting by connecting manually and checking the `SSL Certificate` (A+).

Here is the code I use for loading an image:

```
if let pictureUrl = URL(string: url) {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: pictureUrl)
        img.image = UIImage(data: data)
        if let imageWidth = (img.image?.size.width) {
            let height = width / imageWidth * (img.image?.size.height)!
            conHeight.constant = height
        }
    }
    catch let error {
        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: on `didFinsihLaunch` write `setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1)` & see the prints

Comment: Unrelated but you are strongly discouraged from loading data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`.

Comment: @vadian I am in the process of updating my api calls. Most of them are already asynchronous but I am going to make sure they are all asynchronous and I'm storing my images in a cache with an `NSCache` `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

After writing `setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1)` in:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

as @Jack suggested, I solved the problem. I had errors relating to `Charles` running. After closing Charles, my api calls now work. I probably just need to update the `SSL Certificate` that `Charles` is using because `error 1202` is an SSL Certificate error.